# Displace mesh laterally using noise texture in geometry nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes, displacement, procedural

I need help with replicating the 'Choppiness' setting of the Ocean Modifier using geometry nodes. I can displace the mesh on the z axis and get a very close approximation of the Ocean Modifier with a choppiness setting of zero quite easily using a noise texture. But I think it's the 'Choppiness' factor in the Ocean Modifier that is the real hero and is what gives it that realism. The Blender Manual states that: "*With a choppiness of 0, the ocean surface is only displaced up and down in the Z direction, but with higher choppiness, the waves are also displaced laterally in X and Y, to create sharper wave peaks.*" I cannot work out exactly what is driving the x and y distortion/offset as the 'Choppiness' value is increased. It seems to me to be somehow multi-leveled. The greater the size of the underlying 'wave', the greater the x and y distortion/offset. The noise texture is effectively incrementally smaller 'waves' with the number of compounded layers being dependent upon the 'Detail' setting. I've tried many different node setups (unsuccessfully) based on the assumption that this lateral distortion is driven by a combination of the compounded level of detail in the noise texture, and the resultant normal directions of the mesh from the z axis distortion. If anyone could suggest a node setup that would acheive the same kind of ***lateral*** distortion that the Ocean Modifier 'Choppiness' setting produces, I'd be very greatful.
[image]
Left mesh was created using the Ocean Modifier and the right mesh is the result of the below node setup.
[image]
[image]
[Animation of Choppiness setting from 0 to 2](https://jmp.sh/qhjM5sLV)

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I have just edited the above to hopefully clarify my question.